# Cannot find Symbol Java .toString()

Tags: java

I have been learning Java for three days, I have no idea what I am doing wrong here . Every time I try to run it I get the error message "cannot find symbol" on the second half of "String resultados = Arrays.toString(resultadas);". Please explain this to me without any jargon or technical terms, my brain is too small to comprehend those words... yet

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
public class SquareDigit {
public int squareDigits(int n) {
  String[] result = Integer.toString(n).split("(?!^)");
  int k = 0;
  for (String grade : result) {
     k += 1;
     int resultado = Integer.valueOf(grade);
     int resultada = (int) Math.pow(resultado, 2);
     String[] resultadas = new String[result.length];
     resultadas[k] = Integer.toString(resultada);
  } String resultados = Arrays.toString(resultadas);
  int finals = Integer.parseInt(resultados);
  return finals;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to `import java.util.Arrays;`.

Comment: (And I can't see anything in there requiring the other import)

Comment: That didn't really work; I'm still getting the same error messages

Comment: And I thought I had to to use the Math.pow() method

Comment: The first step to fix an error is to read it, correctly: *Error:(14, 41) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable **resultadas**
  location: class com.bar.SquareDigit*, and *Error:(14, 25) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable **Arrays**
  location: class com.bar.SquareDigit*. I don't know where you got that there was a problem with toString()

Comment: I didn't think that it was a problem with the toString method, just with that specific part of the programming

Comment: Okay, I got it now, it was that the variable was defined within the for loop and I couldn't get it out of it... right?